# Mysql PHP Query select

Tags: php, mysql, select

I want to order desc some rows from mysql table by a numberic value .

Such as: `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ABS(row1) DESC`.

Table format:

> ID | Type | Value
>
> 1  | 2 | 42
>
> 2  | 1 | 52
>
> 3  | 2 | 67
>
> 4  | 2 | 50
>
> 5  | 1 | 15
>
> 6  | 1 | 27
>
> 7  | 3 | 48
>
> 8  | 3 | 23

And i want to get the following result - to sort by value DESC but first show rows with type 2 and DESC and after that the type 1,3,4 (...) rows DESC:

> ID | Type | Value
>
> 3  | 2 | 67
>
> 4  | 2 | 50
>
> 1  | 2 | 42
>
> 2  | 1 | 52
>
> 7  | 3 | 48
>
> 6  | 1 | 27
>
> 9  | 3 | 23
>
> 5  | 1 | 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the `order by` you want:

```
order by `type` = 2 desc,
         value desc
```

The expression `type = 2` returns a boolean value, which is equivalent to 1 when true and 0 when false.  Your example doesn't have negative values, so I don't see a need for `abs()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can sort by two or more fields

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ABS(row1), row2, row3 DESC
```

Comment: I do not want to order the type column, i just want the first rows to be type 2 with value DESC and then value DESC with type 1,3,4,5,6 ...

Comment: I meant that the first results to be rows with type 2 and order by value DESC and after these results to be the rest of the types (not in an order) but order by value DESC . I have updated the main post with type 3 also, to clarify the things. I can do this results in php with two queries but i was wondering if is possible to do this with just one query because i use LIMIT for the results.